# Extract part of a path in c#

Tags: c#, directory, path

Suppose I have the directory path:

```
D:\aa\bb
```

and inside of it can be more file or folders with sub folders

for example

```
D:\aa\bb\test.txt
D:\aa\bb\cc\test.txt
D:\aa\bb\cc\dd\test.txt
```

is there a clean way to extract the right part of the path?

I need something like:

```
string ExtractRightPart(string fullPath)
{
   return ...
}
```

Examples:

For input

```
D:\aa\bb\cc\dd\test.txt
```

the function should return

```
cc\dd\test.txt
```

And for input

```
D:\aa\bb\test.txt
```

the function should return

```
test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public string ExtractRightPart(string fullPath, string leftPath)
    {
        return fullPath.Substring(leftPath.Length);
    }

    ExtractRightPart(@"D:\aa\bb\cc\dd\test.txt", @"D:\aa\bb\");
```

Comment: What happens if full path does not start from the left path?

Comment: Add condition
if(!fullPath.StartsWith(leftPath)) return string.Empty;